# Git: restore files deleted by "git update-ref -d HEAD"

Tags: git

I ran `git update-ref -d HEAD` command, which deleted all my files. The folder size is still large, so, I suppose the files are somehow in git's memory.
How can I recover those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really good way to break your repo;

```
$ mkdir DeleteHead
$ cd DeleteHead/
$ git init
$ touch README.md
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Init."
$ git commit -m "More work" --allow-empty
$ git log
commit 83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Fri Sep 14 17:42:47 2018 +0100

    More work

commit c175c1fbf9ee8b9d2a9eec3eb3666f19db2b9f99
Date:   Fri Sep 14 17:42:38 2018 +0100

    Init.

$ git update-ref -d HEAD
```

And the usual tricks to fix it aren't available to you;

```
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

$ git reflog
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

Let's take a look in the `.git` folder and see what we can find;

```
$ cat .git/logs/HEAD
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 c175c1fbf9ee8b9d2a9eec3eb3666f19db2b9f99 Horba 1536943358 +0100 commit (initial): Init.
c175c1fbf9ee8b9d2a9eec3eb3666f19db2b9f99 83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e Horba 1536943367 +0100 commit: More work
83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Horba 1536943378 +0100
```

That looks handy. Lets grab that `83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e` value (it'll be different in your repo) and update HEAD to be that again;

```
$ git update-ref HEAD 83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e

$ git log
commit 83edc8bcb2e627420e47b7933580dc85b21d968e (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Fri Sep 14 17:42:47 2018 +0100

    More work

commit c175c1fbf9ee8b9d2a9eec3eb3666f19db2b9f99
Date:   Fri Sep 14 17:42:38 2018 +0100

    Init.
```

All fine now.

Comment: Thanks. After following your steps the files were still missing and marked as deleted in `git status`. I ran `git checkout -- .`, and those files recovered. However some files, which were listed in ".gitignore" and thus not tracked were not recovered. However the folder size is still large (it is particularly obvious since those untracked files were the largest). Is there a way to recover those files too?

Comment: It's hard to say. I wouldn't expect `git update-ref -d`  to delete any of the files in your working copy. Did you do anything else like a `git checkout -f` or `git reset --hard HEAD`, things that delete stuff.

Comment: @Horba, I was doing something in GitKraken at the same time (revert, I think). Now a stash showed up there. I applied it, and all the files are back now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `git update-ref HEAD <commit>` also give a error: *fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git*.

Comment: `echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' > .git/HEAD` or `echo <old-head-commit-id>' > .git/HEAD` if you were at the process of rebase worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [Horba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336168/1256452)

The `HEAD` reflog trick is the way to go if possible.  I'll leave my own earlier answer here as well, in case something goes wrong with that approach.

---

(original answer)

> I ran `git update-ref -d HEAD` command, which deleted all my files.

Actually, it didn't: it probably deleted the *branch name* to which `HEAD` was attached (normally `HEAD` is attached to a branch name).

> ... How can I recover?

Run:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

You are likely to see output similar to this, which I ran in a small test repository:

```
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling commit 6719ac33e5c385b9fdba7c57636fbf8cc71a3f3f
```

If you get *exactly one* `dangling commit` along with the `notice` about an unborn branch—in this case `master`; yours will be for whatever branch you just deleted—then this particular commit is (probably; see below for a few edge cases) the one you want:

```
$ git branch master 6719ac33e5c385b9fdba7c57636fbf8cc71a3f3f
```

re-creates it, after which all is back to normal:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

If you get *more than one* `dangling commit` message, run `git show` and/or `git log` on each commit hash ID produced.  One of these will (probably) be the commit you should re-connect.  However, it's possible that you were in the situation described in the next paragraph:

If you get *no* `dangling commit` message, this means you were on a branch that was fully merged into some other branch.  In this case, there is no requirement that you re-create the branch name; you can simply `git checkout` some other branch name to attach `HEAD` there.

Note that if you are on a *detached HEAD* and use `git update-ref -d HEAD`, you will break your Git repository:

```
$ git checkout --detach master
HEAD is now at 6719ac3... initial
$ git update-ref -d HEAD
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

In this case, you must re-create the symbolic `HEAD`.  Unfortunately, normal Git commands refuse to run:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
```

Hence you must cheat:

```
$ echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' > .git/HEAD
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

(this assumes sh/bash commands; modify as needed based on your command environment).